# Command / CLI based REST Http client to process bulk requests (i.e. like .http files)

Tags: webapi, web-api-testing, httpie, postman-newman

Need a tool/setup in place that will trigger RESTful webAPI requests using a preformatted file (which contains Http request config and payload) .. like the .http file format supported by [VScode REST client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client&ssr=false#overview).

We need a CLI because the process is automated and runs in background. A typical scenario will be a .http file arriving in a folder. The tool will pick it up (usually there will be a single Http Request) and trigger that Http request. The response will be output to another file (not mandatory but a logging feature would be helpful in debugging).

Here're a few options we've been exploring -

1. Postman [Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/)
2. CURL with a windows Batch file (or use [HttPie](https://httpie.io/docs) instead of curl)
3. Similar tools we've been exploring - [VScode REST client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client&ssr=false#overview), [httpYAC](https://httpyac.github.io/guide/installation_httpbook.html#installation), .. (not sure if such tools can be automated)
4. A console app based solution - using Node.js, C#, Python, php, ... it'll be highly customizable but this will be like start from scratch. So this is the last option if all the above fails.

We just need this piece to complete our data flow. And we're yet to face things like request throttle, delay, auth, ... but all of this needs to be preconfigured and automated. The setup can very based on the Http service provider we use (i.e. Shopify, Amazon, ...).

EDITT #1 :
Option#5. Forgot to mention that we had implemented a webAPI access demo using **SQL SPs (OLE Automation)** and we could achieve a lot of what we wanted. Here's a similar [Ref](https://www.zealousweb.com/calling-rest-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure/).

Comment: Did you ever find anything?